# Display line with color gradient (or fade effect) based on the value of the vertices it connects

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, linestring, flow-direction

I have two vertices connected by two lines (we can assume way out and way back from point A to point B). In the picture I represented the lines with two arrows curved by adding a midpoint and its offset with the Geometry Calculator. I also made it thicker at the beginning and thinner toward the arrow tip, so that two directions (verses) are already discernible.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0ApV.png]

I want the arrows to be faded close to the origin points and kept well marked close to the destination. Basically I need a gradient fill, but how do I build the gradient based on the values of the vertices?

Comment: Which QGIS version? If using 3.20 or newer, have a look at the new interpolated line symbol layer type, see: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-interpolated-line-symbol-layer-type-for-vector-layers